# Opencv in python : How to find a point through the pipe line?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a set of image for pipe lines which some image have line-crossing.

I try to skeletonize as per [this link to find end point.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235190/how-to-find-endpoints-of-lines-in-opencv)
But the skeleton is returned unwanted ending point and cannot segmentation for line-crossing

[image: Here is the example image]

My goal is to find the list of point from start to end.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are all of them having white background?

Comment: Yes, all of them having a white background.